# allignment 2 arrays c# using loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays for food and price. I want to align both when displayed
like this

```
Food           Price

Food1           Price1
Food2           Price2
Food3           Price3
```

my code so far:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] food = { "Kare-Kare", "Hotdog", "Egg", "Ham", "Pancit Canton" };
Console.Write("FOOD\t\tPRICE\n");
for(int i=0; i<food.Length;i++)
{
    for(int j =i; j<array.Length;j++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(food[i]);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Where is the array of prices?

Comment: how are you wanting to display this @Kevin..? in a DataGrid..? in a ListView.. Printed lines..? please be more specific.. also what is the problem you're having with the current code.. do you know how to debug and step through your own code..? if not read up on how to use the debugger.. by the way keep in mind that array's are `0 based` in C#

Comment: the prices are stored in array varialbe....iim using console app so i would like to display this by line

Comment: ok here's a HINT.. you are using a `\t` in the first Console.WriteLine so why not use the same ` "\t\t"` when inside your loop

Comment: why are you using nested loop humm...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The code does assume that you have as many entries in food as in prices.

```
int[] prices = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
string[] food = { "Kare-Kare", "Hotdog", "Egg", "Ham", "Pancit Canton" };
Console.Write("FOOD\t\tPRICE\n");
for(int i = 0; i < food.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(food[i] + "\t\t" + prices[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: it almost answers the question there is a alignment issue still in regards to the display..

Comment: If OP needs the values aligned, it might worth looking at format strings to pad the output.